# PHP Printing entire HTML friendly input

Tags: php

Currently, I'm allowing users to type in HTML-friendly codes such as `<p>` and `<b>` and so on. However, I'm getting � when there are apostrophies and such in the text.

`$var = ..` get from database..
`$var` contains apostrophies and html elements
echo `$var`

How can I output everything HTML 5 friendly?

Cheers

Comment: Use htmlentities decode

Comment: echo html_entity_decode($text, ENT_COMPAT|ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8");

still not working.

Comment: And what about htmlspecialchars_decode()